# Proxy problems on specific URL in IE

Tags: networking, google-chrome, proxy, internet-explorer

I have a quite weird issue:
I have to use a Proxy-Script for my machine. As usual this is stored in IE under connection settings:

```
http://192.168.21.114/proxy.pac
```

Now everything works just fine except ONE address.

```
https://some-address-for-a-soap-interface.mycomany.com:8043
```

When I enter the address in IE I receive a dnserror after a while. The same happens when trying to connect via telnet. Which seems logical as telnet (and other applications) use the IE-Proxy settings.

Now the weird thing is: Entering the exact same address into Chrome, everything works just fine. AFAIK, chrome also uses the same proxy settings as IE. 
The pac-script is even displayed in `chrome://net-internals/#proxy`

So how can it be that chrome works, but IE doesn't if chrome simply uses the same source configuration?

Needless to say that I prefer that IE (and any system application) works like Chrome and not the other way around.

As the adress looks like it could be an internal address (ends with the TLD of my company) I also tried to disable the proxy completely, but after that it did not work on chrome or IE.

Comment: does it work on other https URLs?

Comment: Yes. No issues at all. I work on this settings everyday using different http & https URLs

Comment: perhaps the proxy uses port 8043 or their firewall blocks it.

Comment: @strobelight if it is simply the firewall/proxy, both browsers should behave identically

Comment: According to the PAC file, should requests to some-address-for-a-soap-interface.mycomany.com be going via proxy or direct to the internet?

Comment: I received another .PAC Url that solved that issue. Cannot really provide any help for others, though